# how to summarise a column and count different values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe such that

```
Time       Name    Vote
20100102   Bob     Positive
20100104   Carlos  Negative
20100106   Kinder  Negative
20100106   Tony    Positive
.
.
.
```

I want to group the data by years and find the number of positive votes and the number of negative votes for different years.
the expected result is:

```
Year    Positive    Negative
2010       1201        891
2011       2039        189
.
.
```

Code used :

```
vote_year <- infile %>%
  group_by(Year = cut(Time,breaks = seq(20100100,20210100,by=10000))) %>%
  summarise(Positive = n(Vote == 'Positive'),Nagative = n(Vote == 'Negative')) %>%
  mutate(Year = seq(2010,2020))
```

I believe the issue is on summarise command, but I don't know how to fix it. It also seems the group_by function does not create an appropriate dataframe.

Comment: Just use `sum` instead of `n`. BTW, you can define the grouping column as `Time %/% 10000`, which is cleaner and doesn't need you to recode it later with `mutate`.

Comment: thank you nicola, shall I change the "Year = " to "Time %>% 10000" to define the names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BaseR

```
table(lubridate::year(lubridate::ymd(df1$Time)), df1$Vote)

#OR

table(substr(df1$Time, 1, 4), df1$Vote)

       Negative Positive
  2010        2        2
  2011        2        0
```

---

`library(janitor)` also helps

```r
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
                  Time       Name    Vote
20100102   Bob     Positive
20100104   Carlos  Negative
20100106   Kinder  Negative
20100106   Tony    Positive
20110104   Carlo   Negative
20110106   Walt    Negative                  ")

library(lubridate)

library(janitor)

library(dplyr)


df1 %>% mutate(year = year(ymd(Time))) %>%
  tabyl(year, Vote)
#>  year Negative Positive
#>  2010        2        2
#>  2011        2        0
```

`Janitor` is more helpful because you can make further useful summary tables like this

```
df1 %>% mutate(year = year(ymd(Time))) %>%
  tabyl(year, Vote) %>%
  adorn_totals(c('row', 'col')) %>%
  adorn_percentages() %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2) %>%
  adorn_ns("front")

  year    Negative   Positive       Total
  2010 2  (50.00%) 2 (50.00%) 4 (100.00%)
  2011 2 (100.00%) 0  (0.00%) 2 (100.00%)
 Total 4  (66.67%) 2 (33.33%) 6 (100.00%)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Year = year(ymd(Time))) %>%
  count(Vote) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Vote, values_from = n)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   Year [1]
   Year Negative Positive
  <dbl>    <int>    <int>
1  2010        2        2
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
                  Time       Name    Vote
20100102   Bob     Positive
20100104   Carlos  Negative
20100106   Kinder  Negative
20100106   Tony    Positive")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option using `dcast` (thank [@AnilGoyal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397652/12158757) for the data)

```
dcast(setDT(df), substr(Time, 1, 4) ~ Vote)
```

which gives

```
   Time Negative Positive
1: 2010        2        2
2: 2011        2        0
```